# Add amount once on duplicate entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Good Day

We have a service department where we go out to service equipment. It sometimes happen that we have more than one job card for a specific client but we can only charge one "CALL OUT FEE" i.e

```
JOB CARD |  CLIENT  |  DATE |  CALL OUT FEE
  121    | AA       | 01/01/2014 | 500
  124    | AA       | 01/01/2014 |  0
```

I Would like to add the CALL OUT FEE only to the first entry where the client and the date is the same in the other entries.

I have no Idea where to start, I guess I have to somehow index the duplicates 1, 2, 3 etc and use HAVING INDEX  = 1 to keep only the first entry.

How would I do this in a very simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `job card` is unique you may try something like this:

```
select * from your_tab 
where job_card in (
    select min(JOB_CARD)
    from your_tab group by CLIENT, DATE
);
```

Comment: Job Card is unique but need only the min(Job card) where CLIENT and DATE is the same. I can only charge one call out fee for a visit. If I have 5 job cards for the same client on the same date there must only be one 500.00 fee charged. Thought it makes sense to add it to the first job card and then add the 0 to the others.

Comment: @Ruan du Preez The query from the answer fits what you've described. For each combination of client + date it finds min job card and then retrieves only rows with min job card

Answer (score 0):

This will update only the first JobCard record for a given ClientCode and Date:

```
DECLARE @CallOutFee MONEY
DECLARE @ClientCode VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Date DATETIME

SET @CallOutFee = 500
SET @ClientCode = 'AA'
SET @Date = '20141125'

UPDATE
  JobCards
SET
  [CALL OUT FEE] = @CallOutFee
WHERE
  JobCardID = (
               SELECT
                MIN(JobCardID)
               FROM
                JobCards
               WHERE
                ClientCode = @ClientCode AND
                [Date] = @Date
              )
```